# redux-form + react-widgets DateTimePicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form, react-widgets

i'm working on reactjs with redux
im trying to implement the following form in the link
https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/examples/react-widgets/

all components working fine except DateTimePicker because of (momentLocaliser)
i tried to implement it in this way :

```
import 'react-widgets/dist/css/react-widgets.css'
import moment from 'moment'
import momentLocaliser from 'react-widgets/lib/localizers/moment'
momentLocaliser(moment)
```

the main issue of implementing momentLocaliser getting (Module not found)

please i need to fix it or if there any date picker i may use with redux-form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you try this

```
npm i react-widgets-moment should be work


import moment from  'moment';
import momentLocalizer from 'react-widgets-moment'
momentLocalizer()
```